# Kotlin auto complete overrides in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, code-completion

I have this variable defined in a Kotlin file, but Android Studio doesn't suggest implementing methods, am I missing something :

```
private val mGestureListener = object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SimpleOnGestureListener` is a non-abstract class. Hence the IDE doesn't show the `Implement methods` options by default. The IDE shows this option only when there is at least one method that's not implemented in the class.

If you want to show the `Override methods` option, then place the cursor inside the braces and choose `Code -> Override Methods...` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>), or if you already know the methods that you want to override, just start typing the method name and it will show up in auto complete.

Answer (score 8):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> inside the `object : Xxx` block to open a dialog to see methods to override, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to see methods to implement.

This is nearly the same as Henry's answer, but he uses mouse, I use keyboard.

Click or press enter on some methods to generate empty implementations, and type letters to do text-based search.

If you didn't find what you expected, you're probably overriding the wrong class/interface.

If you have abstract methods not overriden, you'll see red wave line under `object`. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will help you solve problem in such situation.

Comment: I didn't mention the shortcut key coz I didn't know it for Windows. Seems it's Ctrl + O for windows as well. Anyways, thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: @Henry don't worry :D